# With Xcode 5.1.1 how can I add iOS 7 to xcodebuild? Only iOS 7.1 is shown in -showsdks

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

With Xcode 5.1.1 the command:

`xcodebuild -showsdks`

I get the following output:

```
iOS SDKs:
    iOS 7.1                         -sdk iphoneos7.1

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 7.1             -sdk iphonesimulator7.1
```

How can I use iOS 7.0 with xcodebuild?